# How many fans does a PC need?

Tags: fan, cooling

A friend of mine is looking to buy a new PC. Someone told him that the CPU fan plus the 3 fans on the GPU plus the PSU fan would not be enough and that he needs another 2 or 3 fans so his system could run OK. Is this true, and why?

The system specs are as follows:

- PSU: 650W, FORTRON RAIDER 650, 80+ Silver
- GPU: Gigabyte N770OC-2GD, GTX770, 2GB GDDR5, 256bit, PCI-E
- HDD: 3.5", 1000GB, Seagate Barracuda, 7200rpm, 64MB Cache, SATA3 (ST1000DM003)
- CPU: Intel i5-4670 /3.4GHz/ 6MB Cache/ LGA1150/ BOX (BX80646I54670SR14D)
- Motherboard: GIGABYTE B85M-D3H /Intel B85/ VGA/ LGA1150
- CASE, Delux DLC-MV875 (no PSU)
- RAM: DDR3, KIT 8GB, 2x4GB, 1600MHz, KINGSTON HyperX XMP Blu (KHX1600C9D3B1K2/8GX)

Comment: There's no way we can know with just the information given. At a minimum, we'd need to know what case he's using. But it would also help a lot to know what heat sink, CPU, and power supply he's using. It would also be *very* important to know *precisely* what video card he has. (Some 770GT's exhaust heat [outside](http://videocardz.com/images/2013/05/ASUS-GTX-770-DirectCU.jpg) the case, some [don't](http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/bYvJ3OeIb_8/maxresdefault.jpg)!)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz see the update

Comment: Between `0` and `n` fans.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Got it spot on. Too many variables here.. Give it a whirl  and see how it goes.

Comment: what about dust.  do you want positive pressure (more intake fans) or negative pressure (more exhaust fans)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think he'd be fine without one. The biggest problem is making sure that hot air generated by the CPU and GPU can easily get out of the case. But that's a pretty large case, the video card does a good job exhausting heat from the case, and the power supply draws its inlet air from near the CPU.

Though it's not essential, I would add an additional rear fan. The case has a spot for it. That would both improve airflow around the CPU and GPU and also ensure a stream of air is flowing in the front of the case to help keep drive area cool.

Answer (score 0):

I call BS here.   Intel CPU's generally come with their own heatsink and fan, and anyway these CPU's are low powered devices.

The GPU will typically come with its own fan as well.

In short, the system should run fine with just the fans it comes with provided that you are not trying to overclock it.   Further, the size and speed of the fans plays an important factor in determining the airflow.   Sure more fans are good, but not generally essential.